# NiagaraDataInterfacePhysicsAsset.h and GroomComponent.h in Unreal 5.1 - header not found error while compiling

Tags: compiler-errors, visual-studio-2022, unreal-engine5, niagara-4

i am using UGroomComponent.h in character class , and add the module in .cs file and also regenerated the visual studio file but after compiling the code ,   i am facing another error of Niagara not include in header .

i tried regenerating the visual studio files but still it didn't solve